# Interval is not always cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a heck of time clearing a very simple interval. Sometimes it work and sometimes it doesn't.

I set the interval up when I first launch a Bootstrap modal via:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        getParticipants();

        getParticipantsInt = setInterval(getParticipants, 15000);
    });
```

Then I attempt to clear the interval when a user confirms (via another modal) that they want to delete a user:

```
$("#deleteBtn").click(function() {
            clearInterval( getParticipantsInt );  
            $(parent).closest('tr').remove(); // Remove the row
            test.dropUser(userId)
            .success(function(response){

                    $('#hangupPartModal').modal('hide');
                    setTimeout( function()
                    { 
                        getParticipantsInt = setInterval(getMtgParticipants, 15000);
                    }, 5000);
            });

        });
```

The behavior I want is that as soon as the modal is shown, make a call to the method and then set up an interval to call that method every 15 seconds.

When we delete a user, cancel the interval and basically wait another 20 seconds to restart it.

Problem is that sometimes it's still being called before the 20 seconds is up. In addition, before I delete a user sometimes I can see the getParticipants() method 2 or 3 times in a row.

What am I missing here? Setting/clearing intervals should be easy.

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with the problem, but your two different intervals call different functions, `getMtgParticipants` vs `getParticipants`.  So you're not "restarting" it, you're starting something new.

Comment: Just fixed that; a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        getParticipants();
        clearInterval(getParticipantsint);

        getParticipantsInt = setInterval(getParticipants, 15000);
    });
```

I'm assuming getParticipantsInt is a global. If this is true, the issue is likely that you're having multiple intervals and only clearing one of them.

Comment: Ok, yes. It does appear that I've got multiple intervals running but using this code is not fixing the problem. Not sure what could be causing it.

Comment: I had other issues going on. Your way eventually worked when I cleaned up my code.